# How to load a .mat file and set the variable name in Octave or Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io, octave

Apparently Matlab `load` loads the data from a `.mat` file into the variable that it was saved.

How can you load a single matrix from a .mat or binary file into an arbitrary variable?

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104326/loading-a-variable-from-a-mat-file-into-a-differently-named-variable/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Load it in to a struct and pop it out to your variable.

```
saved_name = 'varname_it_was_saved_as';
s = load('some_file.mat', saved_name);
my_new_variable = s.(saved_name);
```

I always use the struct forms of save and load for production code. It's cleaner because it doesn't dynamically fiddle with your workspace.

See `help load` for details.